# Can I use a PayPal API to retrieve transaction information

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Information I want to retrieve: Name, Address, Amount, Date and so on.

I want to retrieve it from a date (e.g. I want all transaction information since yesterday)

I do not want to use the API to put transactions through, only retrieve the information.

I'm happy to use any of their APIs to achieve this.

I will then want to store this information locally.

After reading the information on their APIs available on their website. I'm lead to believe this can only be done if the transaction has gone through the API. Can you confirm? If it is possible can you point me in the correct direction?

An automatic version of http://www.clovercitysells.com/ebook/csv-export.pdf would be fantastic if it exists.

Comment: This is not possible using the rest API, and the SOAP API wasn't suitable for our system. The alternative I chose was to manually download the CSV file using the "from last run date" option. Then parse.

Comment: Parsing the CSV works to a point, however it doesn't contain shipping address and name, only billing. This may cause problems for some of you, it did for myself.